# How to write a bash script that enters text into programs

Tags: python, bash

I'm writing a bash script that fires up python and then enters some simple commands before exiting. I've got it firing up python ok, but how do I make the script simulate keyboard input in the python shell, as though a person were doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a "here" document. It looks like this

```
command << HERE
text that someone types in
more text
HERE
```

You don'th have to use "HERE", you can use something that has a little more
meaning relative to the context of your code.

Comment: And for the other noobs like me who might not realize: You can change the first HERE, but, if you do you, you have to change the final one two. This page explains > http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: D'oh! yeah, that is important. sorry.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to simulate typing into the Python interpreter, rather than piping a command to python, you can probably do this with [`expect`](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm)

`expect` should be available in your distribution's repository. For details,

```
man expect
```

Comment: this is a good answer. You'd have to use it when you want to do different things based on what came back from Python. It's capable of more of a dialog than a here document, which doesn't really "listen" to python.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `echo "Something for input" | python myPythonScript.py` ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used python, but normally I echo a command string and pipe it to the interpreter binary like so:

```
$ echo '<?php echo "2+2\n"; ?>' | /usr/bin/php
2+2
```

I'm assuming you can do the same w/ python.

Comment: these two work fine (JBernardo's answer too).  A here doc is an option for making multiple lines a little easier to read.